# Hosted Breakpad server (Electron Crash Reporter)

Tags: electron, google-breakpad

I want to setup a service to collect breakpad crash reports (specifically for an Electron app using Electron Crash Reporter: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/crash-reporter.md)

The only servers I can find just dump the minidump and present them in a list which isn't helpful for apps with millions of sessions generating hundreds of crash reports. Something like what Fabric/Crashlytics do for iOS/Android would be ideal (clusters matching reports, sort by release). Also something hosted would be very nice.

- Does a better project exist for collecting breakpad crash reports?
- Are there any good hosted options
- Is there any middleware that will collect breakpad reports and send them to a hosted service like Crashlytics, HockeyApp or Firebase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: I don't have enough reputation to have a post with more than two links :/ All of the items below should be pretty easy to find via a web search.

*Does a better project exist for collecting breakpad crash reports?*

Mozilla's Socorro is an open-source project used by Mozilla to collect breakpad crash reports from applications like Firefox. You can see their instance of Socorro in action by searching for Mozilla crash stats.

*Are there any good hosted options?*

I only know of three companies that provide a hosted breakpad crash management option: Backtrace I/O, Bugsplat and Raygun I/O.
**Full disclosure: I work for Backtrace I/O**

**Backtrace I/O** provides a hosted solution to manage breakpad crash reports generated from electron apps: https://documentation.backtrace.io/product_integration_minidump_electron/index.html. This includes crash aggregation, symbol management, workflow integrations (Slack, JIRA, PagerDuty, etc), custom attributes w/ full reporting on all attributes (you can add custom attributes via `crashReporter.setExtraParameter()`) [edit: fixed spelling] in your Electron app.

**Bugsplat** provides crash aggregation, symbol server, and workflow integrations. AFAICT, it only supports static set of attributes/fields (search for bugsplat breakpad to find their documentation) This means they don't support all of the built-in attributes that Electron reports(`guid`, `process_type`, `platform`, etc) nor do they support extra attributes added via `crashReporter.setExtraParameter()`.

**Raygun**  only officially announced breakpad support via a blogpost mid-April. I can't find any documentation to suggest this is something they actively support. Ragyun's functionality + support for other languages is on-par with other crash-reporting solutions like Crashlytics, HockeyApp, etc.

*Is there any middleware that will collect breakpad reports and send them to a hosted service like Crashlytics, HockeyApp or Firebase?*

I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Follow-up: Backtrace just added Dynamic Symbol Download. Symbols are automatically downloaded from public symbol servers to display human-readable callstacks automatically. [Post here](https://backtrace.io/blog/augustupdate/)

Comment: I just tried Raygun.  It's pretty slick and easy to integrate, but they don't appear to have the ability to actually download the uploaded minidump files.  That seems like a sorely missing feature, since the ability to debug locally with a dump file seems pretty fundamental. 
 Raygun also doesn't update old stack traces when a symbol file is uploaded.  I suspect they don't keep the raw dumps at all.  

I'm trying Backtrace as well.  It's less flashy, but seems to be more feature-rich.

Answer (score 1):

One more new option: https://blog.sentry.io/2018/03/13/introudcing-sentry-electron

Sentry will track native crashes now with their new official electron support. This is a nice option as it also take JS errors for the same app.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option:

The project below project can be deployed to heroku in 1 click. It parses the breakpad dump and passes it on to Sentry.io (a nice hosted service with a free plan). It's not quite 100% hosted (you host the middleware) but only takes 10 mins to setup. Sentry hosts 99% of it, and does excellent issue grouping, reporting, etc.

https://github.com/khamidou/electron-breakpad-sentry